# ImageView wrongfully gets press state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I´ve got an desktop widget with 2 imageviews in an action bar like layout, the "problem" is regardless where in the widget a press (except for btnRefreshWidget) my btnOpen view gets the pressed state. And i can't figure out why. I have looked through my layout and i can´t find anything that looks off, this is my layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widgetItemWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:clickable="false" >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_widget_refresh"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_dark" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnRefreshWidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_widget_refresh"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_dark" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstWidgetList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#40000000" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#40000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="@string/widget_message_noshow"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```